How to render table in discord using discord bot using javascript
Not able to render or work send message in tabular format in discord
I just want to render data in tabular format , Or I can render embed code in discord
Like iframe , so that I can render the iframe on discord , my table contains 12 columns

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
